# Simple JS/jQuery multiple increment and decrement buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, increment

I am working on a personal project to help me understand JavaScript and jQuery better. At the moment I'm working on the store part of my project and have run into a wall.

I'm trying to make my buttons increment and decrement the input separately from each other, but it only updates the first input field.

UPDATED-
HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="panel-body container">
    <h3>Empanada Gallega</h3>
      <p>A savory pie stuffed with Gallicain pork and peppers, onion and oregano.</p>
        <form>
          <div>
            <p class="total-price">$10.50</p>
            <div>
                <input type="button" class="plus-btn plusbtn btn" onclick="plus()">
            </div>

            <input type="text" value="QTY" id="count">

                <div>
                  <input type="button" class="minus-btn btn" onclick="minus()">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h3>Lemon Soda</h3>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <p class="price">$2.00</p>
                    <div>
                      <input type="button" class="plus-btn plusbtn btn" onclick="plus()">
                    </div>

                    <input type="text" value="QTY" id="count">

                    <div>
                        <input type="button" class="minus-btn btn" onclick="minus()">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 let count = 0;
 let countEl = document.getElementById("count");
 function plus(){
     count++;
     countEl.value = count;
 }
 function minus(){
   if (count > 1) {
     count--;
     countEl.value = count;
  }  
}
```

If anyone could help with explaining this to me that would be very helpful.

Update:
Sorry about the confusion. Forgot to add the second item.

My goal is to increment/decrement the second item separately from the first item.

Comment: this seems like it should work, what exactly are you asking?
"but it only updates the first input field"?

Comment: Some web browsers like google chrome and firefox have a web console you can access (F12 on chrome). Look at the error on the console.

Comment: @JoeCodeFrog I have updated the Question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same global variable "count" for all your items,
so every + / - button on your page affects the same global variable, and it is displayed for all the items.

What you want do, is to store a counter for every object.
Try storing individual counters, one for each item.

( After you figure that out, I suggest you try storing an array of items, each with its own counter, and display them in the html dynamically, as that would be a good way of implementing this, and it will help you imrove your software skills ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ )

Comment: Thank you very much. I also appreciate your feedback @JoeCodeFrog :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you want to achieve, but I think there's an issue with your `if()` statement in `minus()` function. It should not check if count > 1 in order to process.
So it should look like:

```
function minus(){
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here could be that `countEl` and `count` are out of scope of your function. Define them within each function.

```
function plus(){
     countEl = document.getElementById("count");
     count = countEl.value;
     count++;
     countEl.value = count;
 }
 function minus(){
   countEl = document.getElementById("count");
   count = countEl.value;
   if (count > 1) {
     count--;
     countEl.value = count;
  } 
}
```

also make sure to set the value in your text box to zero or something else

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="count">
```